# How to restore MySQL DB via command line while closing the SSH session?

Tags: mysql, restore, ssh

I am importing a large MySQL 8 database on Ubuntu 20.04 where the import takes > 24h. Unfortunatelly my provider reconnets every 24h which leads to a stop of the import.

I am issuing this command on a ssh shell which blocks the cursor until finished:

```
mysql -u user -p dbname < /mnt/data/backup/DB_210703.sql 2> import.txt 2>&1
```

The command should also save all output/errors to the txt file import.txt

How can this be changed so that it results in a process number and I can close the session?

Comment: My internet provider cuts the line every 24h.

Comment: There must be a command that does not need to keep the SSH tunnel open. Something like with ampersand &.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a dba problem - this is a sysadmin issue between you and your ISP!

Comment: How is this not a dba problem if one is looking for a possibility to run a restore in the background without keeping an SSH tunnel open?!

Answer (score 1):

[screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)

`screen` is like 'open me a virtual terminal that I can detach from, then re-attach to later'. You use it for long-running processes when you want to disconnect from the box.

You start a screen by entering the command `screen` (and press `enter` to clear the first message). Now you are in a new session. Run what you like. You can `&` it if you like, but I would recommend not as you can then re-connect later to see the output and `Ctrl+C` if you want to stop it.

To detach a screen, hold `Ctrl` then press `A` and `D` one after the other. Not `Ctrl+A+D`, but separate `A` and `D` presses, while holding `Ctrl`.

Now you are back in your old shell. You can now safely disconnect and your task will keep on running. To re-attach later, enter the command `screen -r` and you will get back in. Once you are finished, use `exit` to exit the screen session and drop back to your old shell.

Read the `man` pages about it, as you can open multiple screens at once, name them and reconnect to named sessions. It's quite powerful.